# Mongodb Atlas not getting connected

Tags: database, mongodb, atlas

Previously I was working on mongodb atlas fine with my ethernet connection and everything was perfect. Now I have changed my network to mobile tethering and I am unable to add any data in my database. Below is the attached screenshot. Can anyone tell me is it really the database error or there is something wrong with atlas on tethering connection.
I am working on MEAN STACk.

[image]

Tried to connect atlas multiple times but always gives error when adding data.